# MongoDb group if not already grouped

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Trying to figure out the syntax to make a mongoDB group that would contain the documents that haven't been grouped because it didn't pass the conditional.

Document looks in part like

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("value"), 
"updatedAt" : ISODate("value"), 
"zip" : "11209", 
"state" : "NY", 
"city" : "New York", 
}
```

I created mutually exclusive string arrays for matching the other groups, like

```
east_ny_zipcodes = ["11209", "11210", "11211", ...]
lower_ny_zipcodes = ["11212", "11213", "11214", ...]
```

This is an example query from @Neal Lunn with some defined groups and values

```
db.zips.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "lower_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": [ "$zip", lower_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    },
    "east_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": [ "$zip", east_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    },
    "upper_ny": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": [{ "$in": [ "$zip", upper_ny_zipcodes ] },1,0]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

I would like to create another catch all group that would catch everything that these defined groups didn't, but also give me the documents and not just count so I can drill down into it, something like

```
"other_zips":{
   "$push":{
     "$cond": [{ "$nin": [ "$zip", lower_ny, east_ny, upper_ny,...]}]
}
```

Comment: It would be actually quite helpful if you could add an example of the complete document, so we could follow the river of your thoughts. Otherwise its not clear where for example lower_ny_zipcodes etc. come from.

Comment: Thanks @AlexP. I added an example of the values I used for the lower_ny_zipcodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code.

`all` - variable holding all zip codes

`$$ROOT` - complete document

The below code will push the whole document when not found else it will insert null element.

You can filter the null document in the subsequent stage if you chose.

`$addToSet` will keep atmost one null doc.

Documents:

```
"other_zips_doc":{
   "$addToSet":{
     "$cond": [{ $not: [ { $in: [ "$zip", all ] } ] }, "$$ROOT", null]
  }
}
```

Count:

```
"other_zips_count":{
   "$sum":{
     "$cond": [{ $not: [ { $in: [ "$zip", all ] } ] }, 1, 0]
  }
}
```